# Test Cases for removing all occurrences in substring

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching

Last week I was a giving a hackathon event for my college in which if given a string we need to delete the either first occurence or last occurence of substring,

Example  s= "acaaac" and t ="a"
s is the main string t is the substring

s could be either "caaac" or "acaac",we need to find maximum number of moves for given s and t

input only contains lowercase alphabetic letters [a-z]

Test case 1:
s="aabb" and t = "ab" ,remove the occurence of t in "aabb" s becomes "ab" next remove the only occurrence of the string to get s =""
As there are no more occurrences in s of t we return 2

Test case 2:
s="aabcd" t = "abc" --->only one occurence so count is 1,

Test Case 3:
s="aa"  t = "b"   count =0

i tried following pseudo code in java

```
 count = 0   
 while(s.contains(t))
 {
 s=s.replacefirst(t,"")
 count++;
 }
 return count;
```

but i am not getting which test cases i am missing,i am passing 9 out of 14 in my  event

Can i know which test cases am i missing?

Comment: without the input that fails it won't be easy to help you

Comment: You mentioned, either the first or the last... but you only remove the first here.

Comment: If we give you answers, will you be able to retry them?  If it's too late, then we're just blindly guessing and there's no way we can tell whether our guesses are right, so there's not much reason to put in any effort.  The only thing I can think of is that you might not be handling null or empty strings.  Or maybe your Java code doesn't correctly implement your pseudo-code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah the question is like remove occurences,so doing that ,is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is in a loop, so I think it will remove the first, the last, and everything in between.

Comment: @ajb just want to know ,where am i wrong and is my understanding rite or not

Comment: I don't think we have a way to tell whether your understanding is correct or not, since we can't see the original instructions.

Comment: @ajb what ever in the question i entered here,i think i dint miss any line

Comment: *which if given a string we need to delete the either first occurence or last occurence of substring,* When do you need to delete the **last** occurrence? Because you don't seem to do that. The actual instructions would be helpful. What do you mean by "moves"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where your code will give a wrong answer:

s=ababaa , t=aba

You will remove first occurrence, what will result to:

(aba)baa -> baa -> 1

However if you remove the 2nd occurrence first then you can remove one additional substring:

ab(aba)a -> aba -> '' -> 2

It seems you have to iterate through all the possible combinations of first/last removing and choose the best result.

The more interesting question is if there is a better algorithm rather than brute force?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using **BFS** and I don't think we can do better than brute force, maybe we can add optimizations of ignoring strings which got moves less than `maxMove`s while adding it to queue.

The following code gives the correct output for all the inputs mentioned above.  I've used `JUnit.Assert.assertEquals()`.

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class RemoveString {
    static class Moves {
        String str ;
        int moves ;
        public Moves(String str, int moves) {
            this.str = str ;
            this.moves = moves ;
        }
    }

    static
    public int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
        int max = 0 ;
        if (s == null || t == null || t.length() > s.length())
            return max ;
        Deque<Moves> q = new LinkedList<>() ;
        q.offer(new Moves(s, 0)) ;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            for (int sz = q.size() ;  sz > 0 ; -- sz) {
                Moves curMove = q.poll() ;
                max = Math.max(max, curMove.moves) ;
                if (curMove.str.contains(t)) {
                    int nextStart = curMove.str.indexOf(t, 0) ;
                    if (nextStart != -1) {
                        q.offer(new Moves(curMove.str.substring(0, nextStart) + curMove.str.substring(nextStart+t.length()), curMove.moves+1)) ;
                    }
                    int lastStart = curMove.str.lastIndexOf(t, curMove.str.length()) ;
                    if (lastStart != -1) {
                        q.offer(new Moves(curMove.str.substring(0, lastStart) + curMove.str.substring(lastStart+t.length()), curMove.moves+1)) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return max ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertEquals(3, maxMoves("babba", "b"));
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aabb", "ab"));
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("ababaa", "aba"));
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("abaer", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("erababa", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("zzzeraba", "er")); // Should be 1
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerbabaer", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aeerra", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerera", "er")); // Should be 2
        assertEquals(2, maxMoves("aerbera", "er")); //Should be 2
        assertEquals(1, maxMoves("aberebraba", "er")); // Should be 1
    }
}
```